# Put files uploaded through Google Forms into a Folder specific to one ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is a property management application. Multiple files are uploaded using Forms, over many months there will be many form entries. Also, not all form submissions upload files, some are just inspections and notes. Managers want to see all the files for one property in one folder, named by the Property ID. I found script here that was close and modified it to meet my needs. It works. It creates a new folder if one is not found already existing, and uploads the files to that folder. If the folder for that Property ID is found, it puts the new files there.

The feature I'd like to change: I only want a new folder created when a file is actually uploaded. Right now this script creates a new folder when any data entry is done. The first time it sees an entry for a Property ID, it creates a folder by that name, even if no files were uploaded. So I have a bunch of empty folders.

I'm new to scripts and learning by Google tutorials and trial and error, modifying others' scripts. Here it is. Thanx for any help or advice.

Well I firmly established my rookie status. I tried to copy my code and paste it here but I can't. Get an error that says my code is not properly formatted as code. New question: How do I paste my code here for others to review?

I tried the CTRL-K and it prompts me to enter text.

---

---

Replaced the script above with this:

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '1NQw-ximlmrs3tbi5YXXO9orLJIfmhvS_2yqlHawpKd1VdhNIW1kh54DcmEMo6hBLRXIY9u3n';

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    var subfolderName;
    const files = e.response.getItemResponses().filter(itemResponse => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD").map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse()).reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
    e.response.getItemResponses().forEach(r => { if (r.getItem().getTitle() == 'Enter Property ID') { subfolderName = r.getResponse(); } });
    if (files.length > 0) {
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanx, stumbled a bit, but got it posted.

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you saying this script runs? Where did you find it? For example, there is no command “getFolder_”.

Comment: I messed with that script so much I can't be sure of what's what. I replaced it with another script I found on Stackoverflow. The only edits I made are in quotes in line 1 and line 12. It creates a subfolder under the parent folder when files are uploaded via the Form, and does not create a subfolder when no files are uploaded. Good. But, it creates the a subfolder each time a form is submitted with uploads, even if that subfolder already exists. I need it to put new uploads into the same folder if it already exists. I'll post the new script in my original question.

Comment: Here's my output subfolders. A-022 entries were submitted by 3 different users.

Comment: I need to add code in that second scripts so that if a subfolder already exists created by the name 'Enter Property ID' put the new uploaded files in there. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: OK, delete the first script - it's crap ;) The second script runs fine, and I'll look at your specific problem.

Comment: Good 4 letter description ;) ...done. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move file uploads to a folder names for the "Property ID" but you don't want to create multiple folders of the same "ID".

There are many ways that this can be done; consider the following just one method.

- loop through existing sub-folders and test for an existing folder = the Property ID
- if a subfolder exists, then move the files
- if a subfolder does NOT exist, then crate a subfolder and then the files.

---

```
// the function must be bound to the Google Form
// the function must be triggered by an Event from the Form - Event: onFormSubmit

const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '1n7kMgdkH9n-COYr6-93G0ZsU7Fxqc06OTg2q4T0I1OD3mRYjlNvT6tDlAf-iz-gftfTlPXcf'

function moveFiles(e) {
  try {
    var propID;
    const files = e.response.getItemResponses().filter(itemResponse => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD").map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse()).reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
    e.response.getItemResponses().forEach(r => { if (r.getItem().getTitle() == 'Enter Property ID') { propID = r.getResponse(); } });
 
    if (files.length > 0) {
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID)
      
      // create a new subFolderName?
      // #1: Test for an existing subFolders on Drive
      var subFolders = parentFolder.getFolders()
      var folderExists = 0
      while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = subFolders.next();
        if (folder.getName() == propID){
          folderExists = 1
          var folderID = folder.getId()
        }
      }

      if (folderExists == 1){
        // folder exists
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: don't create a new folder")  
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the folder name = "+propID+", and the id = "+folderID)
      }
      else{
        // a subFolderName does NOT exist, create a new folder
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: create a new folder")
        var subFolderName = parentFolder.createFolder(propID)
        var folderID = subFolderName.getId()
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: New subFolderName name created = "+subFolderName+", id = "+folderID)
      }

      // Logger.log(files) // DEBUG
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of files = "+files.length)
      
      const targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)

      // move the file to the subFolderName     
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(targetFolder)
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f)
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Yes! Works great. My first couple attempts failed until I realized I needed to edit my onFormSubmit trigger to call the moveFiles function you created. Thank you so much for your time and patience with me.

Comment: No worries. If the answer works for you, then you might consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).